# Select element where attribute = "X"

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example3.xsl"?>
<pics>
    <page no="1">
      <pic>
       <td>
         <no src="http://www.templetons.com/brad/pq/playaphone.jpg" width="150" height="120">1</no>
       </td>       
      </pic>
      <pic>
       <td>
         <no src="http://motherjones.com/files/legacy/mojoblog/funny-cats-a10.jpg" width="150" height="120">4</no>
      </td>    
      </pic>
    </page>
    <page no="2">      
      <pic>
       <td>
         <no src="http://motherjones.com/files/legacy/mojoblog/funny-cats-a10.jpg" width="150" height="120">4</no>
      </td>    
      </pic>
      <pic>
       <td>
         <no src="http://www.templetons.com/brad/pq/playaphone.jpg" width="150" height="120">1</no>
       </td>       
      </pic>      
    </page>
</pics>
```

I want using XSL file select only one page
This one gives me both:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pics/page/pic">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="td">
        <td><img>
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="no//@src"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="width">
            <xsl:value-of select="no//@width"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="height">
            <xsl:value-of select="no//@height"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </img></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Where and how can I filter/select or address the no="x" attribute?

Thanks Asaf

Comment: Don't use those `xsl:attribute`. In your case use literal result AVT (like `<img src="{no/@src}"/>`) or just use `xsl:copy-of select="no/@*"`. Also, don't use `//` to select the attributes, just `no/@src` works.

Comment: See my answer for a good and simple solution. Do not use `<xsl:for-each>` -- try not to use it, try to avoid it. Learn something...

Comment: Alejandro and Dimitre Novatchev, thanks for the tips.
I'm in the middle of two projects with new technologies.
My need at the moment for xslt is very basic.

My code looks this way because this was the easiest I could compile from examples people gave me here.

When you say don't use something it is based on experience. Sharing this knowledge could help many others that need more than just "to make it work"

Dimitre ... when I have more time, I'd like to take your advice and learn more :)

I Thank you both very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change this**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pics/page/pic">                    
    <tr>                    
      <xsl:for-each select="td">                    
        <td><img>                    
          <xsl:attribute name="src">                    
            <xsl:value-of select="no//@src"/>                    
          </xsl:attribute>                    
          <xsl:attribute name="width">                    
            <xsl:value-of select="no//@width"/>                    
          </xsl:attribute>                    
          <xsl:attribute name="height">                    
            <xsl:value-of select="no//@height"/>                    
          </xsl:attribute>                    
        </img></td>                    
      </xsl:for-each>                    
    </tr>                    
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**into this**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="pics/page/pic"/>
```

**and add the processing in a template:**

```
<xsl:template match="pic">
 <tr> 
   <xsl:for-each select="td"> 
    <td>
     <img src="{no/@src}" width="{no/@width}" height="{no/@height}"/> 
    <td> 
   </xsl:for-each> 
 </tr> 
</xsl:template>
```

**Then to exclude (filter) a particular pic** (say the 2nd), add this empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="pic[@no='2']"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter on attribute using `[@att='val']`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pics/page[@no='1']/pic">
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pics/page[1]/pic">
```

It should select the first. If you want to select the one with no="1" you can do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pics/page[@no='1']/pic">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="pics/page[@no='x']/pic">
   <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```